# How to start up ECS services in a sequences?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have 3 ECS containers: A, B and C.

Start up time:

- A: 2mins
- B: 1min
- C: 10sec

C depends on B and B on A.

How do I go about starting them in a sequence?

https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/123 - doesn't help me as the containers need to be in one Task Definition which means I can't scale independently.

I tried just doing this but each line is not related to the previous one. So container B can start before container A.

```
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --service serviceA --force-new-deployment
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --service serviceB --force-new-deployment
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --service serviceC --force-new-deployment
```

Comment: Well, you can't do this. Such a thing is not supported. You need to have separate tasks for each container.

Comment: But that means I can't scale each container and, instead, will have to scale out all microservices. That doesn't seem right

Comment: Containers do not scale in ECS. Instead, ECS services scale.

Comment: You can add delay in docker files of containers B and C. You can use RUN SLEEP <time_duration> in docker files

Comment: @Marcin - I meant the service (I know in ECS that means the actual service, which can have 100 containers). So there is no way to do this nicely (Service A relying on Service B). I am surprised tbh as it's such a basic thing

Comment: @SmartCoder - I will do that as a last resort. Having a hardcoded delay is never a good idea

Comment: Steps functions could allow you to orchestrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a [wait](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/wait/index.html) between each of your update calls:

```
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --service serviceA --force-new-deployment
aws ecs wait services-stable --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --services serviceA 
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --service serviceB --force-new-deployment
aws ecs wait services-stable --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --services serviceB
aws ecs update-service --region us-east-1 --cluster clusterName --service serviceC --force-new-deployment
```

Comment: Wow - I didn't know about and belive me I have searched :)

Comment: Tried it today and works like a charm! Thanks a bunch mate